# problemas fadeToggle toggle de jquery

Tags: jquery

como sabran la function `toggle` quedo obsoleta en la version de jquery 3.1 recuerdo qque en versiones anteriores podia hacer lo siguiente

```
$("button").toggle(function(){


    $("p").hide()//just an example hide p tags
   $("div").html("Goodnight stackoverflow comunity");
},function(){


    $("p").show()//just an example show p tags
     $("div").html("Goobye stackoverflow comunity");

})
```

este codigo lo que hacia era que al pinchar un boton me escondia las etiquetas `p` y agragar un texto a un div luego al pincharlo otra ves las escondia y cambiaba el contenido del div , pero esto quedo obsoleto desde la version de  **jquery 3.1.1** como podria hacer lo mismo en las nuevas versiones de jquery?

es decir nececito hacer algo similar a ese codigo mediante un click a un boton mostrar un div con una informacion y cambiar un texto de `show info` a `hide info` y viceversa intente lo siguiente pero solo me hace el toggle del div pero no me cambia el texto este es mi codigo:

```
$(document).on("click",".info",function(e){

 e.stopPropagation();

    $(".show-info").stop().fadeToggle(function(){

              $("#show").html("hide");

     },function () {

        $("#show").html("Show");
    });

        })


     $("html").click(function(){

     $(".show-info").stop().slideUp();
       })


    })
```

alguien que me de una mano gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo que estabas buscando es la función `slideToggle()`. Lo que hace es que si el elemento al que se lo aplicas está oculto lo muestra, y si está visible lo oculta.

Para controlar el texto que se ha de mostrar le añado además al párrafo una clase que uso a modo de control y así diferencio cuando el texto está oculto o no. Como ves, existe una función llamada `toggleClass()` que nos viene muy bien para que funcione a la par de nuestro `slideToggle()`.

**HTML**

```
<p id="miParrafo">
Escóndeme
</p>
<div>
  <p>
    Goodnight stackoverflow comunity
  </p>
</div>

<button id="miBoton">
  ¡Pínchame!
</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#miBoton').click(function () {
    $('#miParrafo').slideToggle();
  $('#miParrafo').toggleClass('escondido');

  if ($('#miParrafo').hasClass('escondido')) {
    $('div p').html('Goodnight stackoverflow comunity');
  }
  else {
    $('div p').html('Goobye stackoverflow comunity');
  }

});
```

Comment: Genial no sabia exactamente sobre `toggleClass` gracias amigo !!

Comment: Con ese ejemplo podría seguir usando `toogle()`. El método [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) de animación no se ha eliminado, el que se quitó es el evento [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). Es confuso porque se llaman igual

Answer (score 3):

En realidad la funcion `toggle()` quedó desaprobada en jQuery 1.8 y se eliminó en la versión 1.9.

Podrias usar un marcador que cambie cada vez que pulsas el botón, algo así:

```js
var flag = true;
$('button').click(function() {
  if (flag) {
    $("p").hide() //just an example hide p tags
    $("div").html("Goodnight stackoverflow comunity");
  } else {
    $("p").show() //just an example show p tags
    $("div").html("Goobye stackoverflow comunity");
  }
  flag = !flag;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click aquí</button>
<p> párrafo </p>
<div></div>
```